# VSS 2005 and VS 2008 out of sync, how to I resolve this?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

There's a project I have in Visual SourceSafe 2005, that I maintain and edit using Visual Studio 2008. In VS 2008 it shows all of the files as being checked out. But within VSS 2005 it shows no one as having any file checked out of the project. Furthermore, if I try to checkout the project in VS 2008, it gives me a message saying that I'm offline (which is wrong) and it wants to work in an offline fashion. How do I get VS 2008 to be in sync with VSS 2005?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Visual Studio menu File->Source Control->Change Source Control and try connecting to the SourceSafe version control there.